# best way to import xml into mysql using ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, xml, xml-parsing

After having searched I found the following resources:

http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_xml_xslt.htm

Before trying them out I just want to make sure maybe there better ways to import values of the nodes/tags of xml file into mysql (from one xml file to more than one table in mysql) that maybe someone already does these days.

Writing this, I also feel like the point is not how to import xml into mysql, but how to read the values of the xml file and writing them into mysql maybe a different question...

I apologise in case my question is not much clear.

Sample xml file looks like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ShipmentRequest>
   <Message>
      <Header>
      <MemberId>MID-0000001</MemberId>    
      <MemberName>Bruce</MemberName>
      <DeliveryId>0000001</DeliveryId>
      <OrderNumber>ON-000000001</OrderNumber>
      <ShipToName>Alan</ShipToName>
      <ShipToZip>123-4567</ShipToZip>
      <ShipToStreet>West</ShipToStreet>
      <ShipToCity>Seatle</ShipToCity>
       <Payments>
        <PayType>Credit Card</PayType>
        <Amount>20</Amount>
      </Payments>
      <Payments>
        <PayType>Points</PayType>
        <Amount>22</Amount>
      </Payments>
      <PayType />
      </Header>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>3.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>A-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Apple</Description>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>5</UnitCost>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>4.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>P-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Peach</Description>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>6</UnitCost>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>5.1</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>O-0000001</ItemId>
      <Description>Orange</Description>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <UnitCost>4</UnitCost>
    </Line>
  </Message>
</ShipmentRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the XML structure in the database, this is a non-trivial task. One of the most simple ways I know is using the [dewey labeling scheme](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1897505), and it doesn't performs very bad.

However, if you just want to read the XML and create your own custom queries, you can just use one XML parser as SimpleXML, Nokogiri or REXML and create your custom queries.

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice and experiments with the ways above.